# boost::multi_index_container: issue in retrieving end iterator

Tags: c++, boost, iterator, boost-multi-index

I have a Color class.

I want to create a [boost::multi_index_container](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_59_0/libs/multi_index/doc/index.html) that uses a color ID and a color position (it's inside a gradient class) as keys.

In order to maintain the code more readable, I've encapsulated the boost implementation in my `IndexedColorSet` class.

I want to retrieve the colors ordered by their position. In order to do this I've created a `getStartEndPositionIterators` method that returns begin and end iterator of the multi_index_container ordered by position.

My problem is that ending iterator seems to do not work properly. If I create a loop that print position of all iterators from begin to end, they are printed properly, but when I reach the end iterator it cycles indefinitely between last stored value and an invalid value.

How can I retrieve the right end iterator? What I'm doing wrong?

Using boost 1.58.0 and gcc 5.2.1.

```
#include <boost/multi_index_container.hpp>
#include <boost/multi_index/ordered_index.hpp>
#include <boost/multi_index/identity.hpp>
#include <boost/multi_index/member.hpp>
#include <utility>
#include <iostream>

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
/// Class that must be inserted into multi_index_container. //
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

class Color {
public:
    double red;
    double green;
    double blue;
    double alpha;
};

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////
/// Class that implements the multi_index_container //
/// using ordering by id and by position.           //
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////

class IndexedColorSet {
public:

    // Class that wil be used as multi_index_container template parameter.
    class IndexedColor {
    public:
        int id;
        double position;
        Color color;
        IndexedColor() {}
        IndexedColor(int id, double position, const Color &color) :
            id(id), position(position), color(color) {}
    };

    // typedef for multi_index_container iterator
    typedef ::boost::multi_index::detail::bidir_node_iterator<boost::multi_index::detail::ordered_index_node<boost::multi_index::detail::index_node_base<IndexedColor, std::allocator<IndexedColor> > > > PositionIterator;

public:

    void insertColor(int id, double position, const Color &color);
    // Retrieve begin and end iterator using position as index
    std::pair<const PositionIterator&, const PositionIterator&> getStartEndPositionIterators() const;

private:

    // Tags
    struct id{};
    struct position{};

    // Container creation.
    // It creates an ordered_unique index using id
    // and a ordered_not_unique index using position
    typedef ::boost::multi_index_container<
        IndexedColor,
        ::boost::multi_index::indexed_by<
            ::boost::multi_index::ordered_unique<
                ::boost::multi_index::tag<id>,
                BOOST_MULTI_INDEX_MEMBER(IndexedColor,int,id)
            >,
            ::boost::multi_index::ordered_non_unique<
                ::boost::multi_index::tag<position>,
                BOOST_MULTI_INDEX_MEMBER(IndexedColor,double,position)
            >
        >
    > PrivateIndexedColorSet;

private:

    PrivateIndexedColorSet m_set;
};

// Insert a color associated to id and position.
void IndexedColorSet::insertColor(int id, double position, const Color &color) {
    m_set.insert(IndexedColor(id, position, color));
}

// Retrieve a std::pair containing begin and end iterator if multi_index_container
// using the position as key.
std::pair<const IndexedColorSet::PositionIterator&, const IndexedColorSet::PositionIterator&> IndexedColorSet::getStartEndPositionIterators() const {
    const auto& positionSet = ::boost::multi_index::get<position>(m_set);
    const auto& beginIt = positionSet.begin();
    const auto& endIt = positionSet.end();
    return std::pair<const PositionIterator&, const PositionIterator&>(beginIt, endIt);
}

int main()
{
    IndexedColorSet set;

    // Populate the set
    int id1 = 1;
    int id2 = 2;
    int id3 = 3;
    double position1 = 0.4;
    double position2 = 0.6;
    double position3 = 0.3;
    Color color1{0.1, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5};
    Color color2{0.2, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6};
    Color color3{0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6};
    set.insertColor(id1, position1, color1);
    set.insertColor(id2, position2, color2);
    set.insertColor(id3, position3, color3);

    // Retrieve ordered position iterators
    auto iterators = set.getStartEndPositionIterators();

    // Testing that are ordered
    // I should obtain
    // 0.3
    // 0.4
    // 0.6
    //
    // Instead I obtain
    // 0.3
    // 0.4
    // 0.6
    // 0
    // 0.6
    // 0
    // 0.6
    // 0
    // 0.6
    // 0... and so on
    for (auto it = iterators.first; it != iterators.second; ++it) {
        std::cout << it->position << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Out of the box, you might be interested in Container libraries: [live demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/cc9475e14b7db2d1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The library author already showed you the main problem. Here's the live-coded cleanup that I have had the joy of going over with you :)

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/144d882399a3a9b2)</kbd>**

```
#include <boost/multi_index_container.hpp>
#include <boost/multi_index/ordered_index.hpp>
#include <boost/multi_index/member.hpp>
#include <boost/range/iterator_range.hpp>
#include <iostream>

struct Color {
    double red;
    double green;
    double blue;
    double alpha;
};

namespace bmi = boost::multi_index;

class IndexedColorSet {
  public:

    struct IndexedColor {
        int id;
        double position;
        Color color;
    };
  private:

    typedef bmi::multi_index_container<
        IndexedColor,
        bmi::indexed_by<
            bmi::ordered_unique<     bmi::tag<struct by_id>,       bmi::member<IndexedColor, int,    &IndexedColor::id>       >,
            bmi::ordered_non_unique< bmi::tag<struct by_position>, bmi::member<IndexedColor, double, &IndexedColor::position> >
        >
    > PrivateIndexedColorSet;

  public:
    // typedef for multi_index_container iterator
    using PositionIterator = PrivateIndexedColorSet::index<by_position>::type::const_iterator;
    using PositionRange    = boost::iterator_range<PositionIterator>;

    void insertColor(int id, double position, const Color &color);
    PositionRange getPositionRange() const;

  private:
    PrivateIndexedColorSet m_set;
};

// Insert a value
void IndexedColorSet::insertColor(int id, double position, const Color &color) {
    m_set.insert({id, position, color});
}

// Retrieve the full range by_position
IndexedColorSet::PositionRange IndexedColorSet::getPositionRange() const {
    auto& positionSet = bmi::get<by_position>(m_set);
    auto beginIt      = positionSet.begin();
    auto endIt        = positionSet.end();

    return { beginIt, endIt };
}

int main() {
    IndexedColorSet set;

    // Populate the set
    set.insertColor(1, 0.4, {0.1, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5});
    set.insertColor(2, 0.6, {0.2, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6});
    set.insertColor(3, 0.3, {0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6});

    // Retrieve ordered position iterators
    auto iterators = set.getPositionRange();

    for (auto& ic : iterators) {
        std::cout << ic.position << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Prints

```
0.3
0.4
0.6
```

Comment: See the [recorded live stream](https://www.livecoding.tv/video/review-mulitindex-container-application/) in case you wanted to catch my initial response still :)

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that `getStartEndPositionIterators` returns a pair or *references* to iterators, when you want to return the iterators themselves (references refer to objects inside `getStartEndPositionIterators` that become invalid as soon as the member function exits):

```
std::pair<PositionIterator,PositionIterator> getStartEndPositionIterators() const;
```

I've cleaned up your code a bit: in particular, the way you're getting the type of `PositionIterator` is absolutely not documented, you can do it the legal way as shown below.

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4f92ef336da3dd43)</kbd>**

```
#include <boost/multi_index_container.hpp>
#include <boost/multi_index/ordered_index.hpp>
#include <boost/multi_index/identity.hpp>
#include <boost/multi_index/member.hpp>
#include <utility>
#include <iostream>

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
/// Class that must be inserted into multi_index_container. //
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

class Color {
public:
    double red;
    double green;
    double blue;
    double alpha;
};

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////
/// Class that implements the multi_index_container //
/// using ordering by id and by position.           //
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////

class IndexedColorSet {
public:

    // Class that wil be used as multi_index_container template parameter.
    class IndexedColor {
    public:
        int id;
        double position;
        Color color;
        IndexedColor() {}
        IndexedColor(int id, double position, const Color &color) :
            id(id), position(position), color(color) {}
    };

private:

    // Tags
    struct id{};
    struct position{};

    // Container creation.
    // It creates an ordered_unique index using id
    // and a ordered_not_unique index using position
    typedef ::boost::multi_index_container<
        IndexedColor,
        ::boost::multi_index::indexed_by<
            ::boost::multi_index::ordered_unique<
                ::boost::multi_index::tag<id>,
                BOOST_MULTI_INDEX_MEMBER(IndexedColor,int,id)
            >,
            ::boost::multi_index::ordered_non_unique<
                ::boost::multi_index::tag<position>,
                BOOST_MULTI_INDEX_MEMBER(IndexedColor,double,position)
            >
        >
    > PrivateIndexedColorSet;

public:

    void insertColor(int id, double position, const Color &color);
    // Retrieve begin and end iterator using position as index
    typedef PrivateIndexedColorSet::index<position>::type::iterator PositionIterator;
    std::pair<PositionIterator,PositionIterator> getStartEndPositionIterators() const;

private:

    PrivateIndexedColorSet m_set;
};

// Insert a color associated to id and position.
void IndexedColorSet::insertColor(int id, double position, const Color &color) {
    m_set.insert(IndexedColor(id, position, color));
}

// Retrieve a std::pair containing begin and end iterator if multi_index_container
// using the position as key.
std::pair<
  IndexedColorSet::PositionIterator,
  IndexedColorSet::PositionIterator>
IndexedColorSet::getStartEndPositionIterators() const {
  return std::make_pair(
      m_set.get<position>().begin(),
      m_set.get<position>().end());
}

int main()
{
    IndexedColorSet set;

    // Populate the set
    int id1 = 1;
    int id2 = 2;
    int id3 = 3;
    double position1 = 0.4;
    double position2 = 0.6;
    double position3 = 0.3;
    Color color1{0.1, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5};
    Color color2{0.2, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6};
    Color color3{0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6};
    set.insertColor(id1, position1, color1);
    set.insertColor(id2, position2, color2);
    set.insertColor(id3, position3, color3);

    // Retrieve ordered position iterators
    auto iterators = set.getStartEndPositionIterators();

    // Testing that are ordered
    // I should obtain
    // 0.3
    // 0.4
    // 0.6
    for (auto it = iterators.first; it != iterators.second; ++it) {
        std::cout << it->position << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: ＋1 I spent some more time cleaning up / reviewing but you nailed it, obviously

Comment: Thanks It helped me a lot.